# No available VMware CPU licenses BUT assigned license count does not match the real used count

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

My vSphere client 5.1.0 shows a license key for 6 CPU (**6** is displayed in both **`Assigned`** and **`Capacity`** columns) but **ONLY** two 2-socket hosts (i.e. 4 CPU) are listed. Therefore two CPU licenses are unused.

[image: 4 from 6 CPUs]

But when I try to assign that license key to a new 2-socket ESXi host, the count of CPU licenses available is ZERO (none) -- **two CPU licenses are missing**.

[image: No CPU license availabe]

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us this with images please.

Comment: @Chopper3, here you have the snapshots

Comment: It's weird to see a problem with vSphere _5.1_, but is there any chance you can call this in to support?

Comment: That's really weird, have you been able to reboot the vCenter since spotting this problem?

Comment: @ewwhite, I'm new in this company and I still do not know the VMware support contact for this company.

Comment: @Chopper, I did not reboot the vCenter.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the VMware document **1027410**, titled [**vCenter Server incorrectly displays the amount of licenses in use by ESX hosts**](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1027410). And also found a web page where that [VMware procedure is applied](http://www.running-system.com/vcenter-more-licenses-assigned-than-in-use-by-esxi-hosts)

I have followed the steps from 1 to 10 and I have found some **host IDs** in the **ADAM database** which are *duplicated* IDs, according to the step 11. The next move is to remove these **host IDs** from the **ADAM database** <s>but I am concerned about the effects on the vCenter running</s>.

**update**: I carried out the **[VMware proceduce](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1027410)** and it worked fine. After removing the first *duplicated* ID, 2 CPU licenses appeared:

[image]

Best Regards

---

P.D: Firstly, I was confused by the terminology in that [VMware procedure](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1027410). However I realized the **ADAM database** is not the SQL/Oracle database, but the LDAP instance checked in steps 2 to 8.